# read xml file using xmlreader

Tags: c#

i want to read xml file using xmlreader. i having xml file. in which i want to fine brandname using brandcode...

```
    <Root>
- <data>
  <Companycode> TF</Companycode> 
  <Productcode>00001</Productcode> 
  <Productname>VPU</Productname> 
  <Brandcode>001</Brandcode> 
  <Brandname>DB</Brandname> 
  </data>
- <data>
  <Companycode>TF</Companycode> 
  <Productcode>00002</Productcode> 
  <Productname>SENDERCARD</Productname> 
  <Brandcode>002</Brandcode> 
  <Brandname>LINSN</Brandname> 
  </data>
```

Comment: Zafar is right. Provide some code which you have tried and what kind of issue you are facing in it?

Comment: are you sure you want to use xmlreader? do you have to ? LINQ-to-XML would probably be easier

Comment: Why do you want to use XmlReader?  It looks like a bad choice.

Comment: i used the following code,XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml("codedata.xml");
                XmlNodeList xmlnodel = doc.SelectNodes("Root/data");
                foreach (XmlNode xns in xmlnodel)
                {
                    string brandname = xns["Brandcode"].InnerText;
                }.it showing error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Don't add important details in a comment, _edit_ the question.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to use serialization/deserilization and defining a class that map your
node like :

```
class Product
{
string CompanyCode;
string ProductCode;
string ProductName;
...
```